# how to make Java PDF exclusive file explorer/viewer

Tags: java, file, pdf, explorer

I am fairly new a Java programing and i have been tasked with building a Java file explorer, but it must be PDF exclusive. It must be able to search the entire HDD for PDF files and be able to list them and make them available to be viewed by double clicking them. It must also have a refresh button that way you don't have to close and re-open the program so search and view another file. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I have also made this as the GUI I'm going to us for the file explorer

```
package pdfView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class View extends JFrame {
    public View() {
        super("PDF Viewer");
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(500, 125);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(flo);
        JTextField Search = new JTextField ("Search", 29);
        JButton Search1 = new JButton("Search");
        JButton ReFresh = new JButton("ReFresh");
        add(Search);
        add(Search1);
        add(ReFresh);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                    "com.sun.java.squing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
                    );
        } catch (Exception exc){

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        View pdf = new View();
    }

}
```

Comment: So what will be your part in this assignment?

Comment: This question is too broad; you're going to need some more research, and ensure you write your questions so it doesn't appear like you're asking us to write it for you. Do some googling and attempt to build this first, then feel free to come back when you've encountered a more specific problem or question that hasn't been answered before.

Comment: I worded it wrong, I was just looking for example code and a little direction, I wasn't looking for some one to make it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would use [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).  It is built into java by default.  You can also filter the files so that only .pdf documents show up.  From there, there are several libraries that let you extract text from the pdf such as [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/).